# Issue with executing net use command through telnet session

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, cifs, telnet

When executing net use command for mapping cifs share to windows drive.

The drive is available only for that **telnet session.**

But when i am doing it manually the drive is available permanent.

Command:**net use T: \172.27.4.222\Secure /USER:smbuser password /PERSISTENT:YES**

How to make that **disk is available permanent through Telnet session**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the telnet session permanent? When are you losing the mapping, when you disconnect and then reconnect with telnet?

Comment: My requirement is to map that disk permanently using telnet.When executing command it completes successfully. But when i rd to that windows machine im not able to see the disk. But i m able to execute commands in the telnet session and changes are effected on that Cifs share.